# Asus z53 laptop overheating problem

Tags: laptop, cleaning, cooling

I'm wondering if anyone encountered overheating of an Asus laptop? Especially the z53 model?

Usually the right side of the laptop and vent in the upper corner is blowing hot air when under even minimal load.  The CPU temperature can easily get to 65-70C and GPU is even above 80C. I'm using NHC (Notebook Health Control) to set to a higher conservatory power consumption, but that helps only a bit.

Has anyone opened up the case?  I'm wondering if it requires a dust cleaning, etc.  I still have some warranty on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I opened up my son's Asus laptop, don't remember the model, and there was a thick layer of dust where air enters the heatsink -- it looked like a piece of felt.  After removing it his system ran a lot cooler.

Comment: I'm definitely going to open up the case of my laptop soon. thanks

Comment: i've had overheating issues with an emachines laptop since it was purchased; opening it up and cleaning it out regularly (say, once a year) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing, after cleaning up the cooler from dust accumulated in time, the temperature dropped to 45-50C even on heavier loads.